# Decypting an MS-Access 2003 Backend?

Tags: encryption, ms-access-2003, jet, cracking

From [what I've read](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Changing-the-encryption-type-in-Access-2007) the encryption on an MS-Access 2003 database (*.mdb) is pretty weak.

I'm working with a legacy JET/MS-Access 2003 database which I have frontend and odbc access to, and I'm having a difficult time using the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for Access to port the data.  When importing, most of the tables say that the tables are encrypted.

Are there any tools to crack MS-Access 2003 encryption?  Is there a way to find out what encryption was used to encrypt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Is there a way to find out what encryption was used to encrypt it?*

For Access 2003, I think there is only one type of encoding used. The following is quoted from [Encryption level for 2003](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/encryption-level-2003-a-t2624066.html):

*Access uses RC4 encryption with a 32-bit key which is stored in the header
of the file. It is often referred to as "encoding" rather than "encryption"
because it is always fully reversible since the encryption key is always
available (no matter if you apply ULS or not).*

- *Are there any tools to crack MS-Access 2003 encryption?*

Maybe, but I don't know of any.  I would open the db file in Access 2003 and use Tools->Security->Encode/Decode Database to create a decoded copy and migrate the copy to SQL Server.  If you don't have Access installed, you should still be able to use `dbDecrypt` (value = 4) as option for the `CompactDatabase` method.

```
DBEngine.CompactDatabase olddb, newdb, locale, options, password
```

Comment: Is the password the password for decrypting the database, or the password to the security file?

Comment: The password parameter is a placeholder for an optional database password.  In Access 2003, the database password and database encoding/encryption are independent. In Access 2007, they are used together for the purpose of "encrypt with database password".

Comment: Wait, so you're telling me that the database can be encrypted without a password in Access 2003? Shouldn't I need a username too?

Comment: And what is the DBEngine.CompactDatabase thing?  Is that in Visual Basic?

Comment: Yes, Access 2003 will encode a db without a password.  I tested yesterday to confirm.  The only reason you would need a user name is if the database had been "secured" with Jet ULS (user level security).

Comment: "*The DBEngine object contains and controls all other objects in the hierarchy of DAO objects*".  You can use it from VBA.  Or use `CreateObject()` to get it from VBScript.  I don't know how it would be done from other VB flavors, but since it can be done from VBScript, it should be possible.